# Wordpress.org Vs. Bitnami Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bitnami

I got really confuse about these two. I am new to Wordpress and want to make website for business. Which one should I take? My purpose is to design and build website only and not for hosting and ssl certification. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress is a content management platform distributed by WordPress.org.
Bitnami is a way to install the entire LAMP stack, including WordPress.

For example, I have sites on DreamHost shared hosting, DreamHost managed VPS, and on my own VPS on DigitalOcean. All run exactly the same version of WordPress, downloaded from wordpress.org.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/which-wordpress-should-i-download/